# Identification environment in PHP when script run with CLI

Tags: php, command-line, environment, ipconfig

I'am using apropriate  config for each environment. In order to acomplissh that i have to identify with 'HTTP_HOST' variable , for example:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='example.com'){
```

the problem is that when i run the code from cli , locally i can't figure out what is the environment.

i found some code that solve my problem

```
function getIPs($withV6 = true) {
     preg_match_all('/inet'.($withV6 ? '6?' : '').' addr: ?([^ ]+)/', `ifconfig`, $ips);
   return $ips[1];
}
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='example.com'||getIPs()[0]=='55.789.258.66'){
```

But  `ifconfig` works only in linux , i identify which OS and change 'ifconfig' to 'ipconfig'(windows )  using:

```
$getIpFunc = PHP_OS=='Linux'?`ifconfig`:`ipconfig`;
preg_match_all('/inet'.($withV6 ? '6?' : '').' addr: ?([^ ]+)/', $getIpFunc, $ips);
```

but i don't receive the ip in windows

Comment: I'm not into windows but is it not `ipconfig /all` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `getHostByName` in both environments. It would probably be more reliable than using ipconfig or ifconfig.

```
$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: Glad to help :) please mark this as `correct` if it solved your problem.